# How to know exactly the type of bluetooth dongle I have?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

My desktop computer doesn't have innate bluetooth capability. SO I put a bluetooth dongle there.

It works.

I can listen to bluetooth headset with it.

However, the mic doesn't work.

I think it has csr 4.0 written on it.

I want to know the exact type of bluetooth dongle. Is there a software to do so?

I tried belarc advisor but it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Looks like you didn't attempt to Google "csr 4.0"  From the endless links on the first page, this seems to have a fair amount of information about it: http://www.dx.com/p/ultra-mini-bluetooth-csr-4-0-usb-dongle-adapter-black-143276.

Comment: @fixer1234 Your link is 404 :/

Comment: @DavidPostill, Thanks.  The link must have gotten corrupted: http://www.dx.com/p/ultra-mini-bluetooth-csr-4-0-usb-dongle-adapter-black-143276